# How to disable Windows Search in Windows explorer

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-search

Someone installed [Windows Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Search) on my computer and I hate it. I refuse to spend time setting up the indexer. I just want it gone!

How can I remove it and its indexer from my computer, or at least get Windows Explorer to default to using the [Search Companion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Explorer#Search_companion) like it used to?

Comment: I found this to be pretty good after I removed Windows Search. I use http://www.mythicsoft.com/filelocatorlite

Comment: See also [Can I configure windows search service only for Outlook, but NOT SearchIndexer?](http://superuser.com/questions/623196/can-i-configure-windows-search-service-only-for-outlook-but-not-searchindexer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to head over to Add/Remove programs and remove it that way. As Diago mentions below, you may have to show the hidden updates to see it.

Comment: I don't see it in Add/Remove programs

Comment: I assume you are using Windows XP? It would be "Windows Desktop Search 4.0" or something like that.

Comment: In Add/Remove you need to check the box to show updates. It is part of Windows Updates now

Answer (score 4):

It's located at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows Desktop Search\DS`

**not** `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows Desktop Search\DS`
as another answer suggested.

Answer (score 3):

In RegEdit, go to

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows Desktop Search\DS
```

and set `ShowStartSearchBand` to `0`, and you'll get the default search behavior back.

Answer (score 2):

You can Disable the service.

- Go To Control Panel->Administrative Tools->Services
- Go down to Indexing Service and change the Startup Type to "Disable"

Comment: I've already done that, but I want to also figure to how to make the old window search panel show up in Windows Explorer when clicking the search button.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably seen as a Windows update, you need to look in the list of installed Windows Updates.