# Can I configure windows search service only for Outlook, but NOT SearchIndexer?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, services, windows-search, windows-services

Outlook 2010 seem to rely it's search features on windows search, in windows 7. I want to disable SearchIndexer.exe from indexing my hard drives, permamently. However I wish to keep the search functionality of Outlook.

Can Windows Search, or Outlook be configured so SearchIndexer.exe won't run or won't index any of my hard drives, but Outlook still be able to search?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run the Indexing options from control panel or via this command:

```
"C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe" C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL C:\Windows\System32\srchadmin.dll
```

and remove all entries except Outlook emails.